# Smooth 2D data with holes in Python

Tags: python, filter, nan

I have 2D data in a numpy array in Python which looks like this:

[image]

I want to smooth it and came across [`scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.gaussian_filter). The problem I am having is that since my data has holes filled with `NaN` values, as seen in the above image, these `NaN` lagoons get bigger with the smoothing:

[image]

Is there a function that has something like *ignore NaN* or so, that avoids this issue?